# SQL*Plus version not printing in tempfile

Tags: shell-script, windows, sqlplus

I am trying to execute below Unix script to fetch the Oracle version from Windows command prompt using `ssh` command to connect to Unix terminal.

```
#!/use/bin/ksh
Freport=/tmp/test.txt
cd /usr/oracle2/product/11.2.0/bin
echo "Begin" > $Freport
set +x
/usr/oracle2/product/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus -V >> $Freport
set -x
pwd >> $Freport
echo "Completed" >> $Freport
```

Windows command prompt output:

```
Begin
/usr/oracle2/product/11.2.0/bin
Completed
```

Same script ran in Unix server and got below output.

Putty output:

```
Begin

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0

/usr/oracle2/product/11.2.0/bin
Completed
```

I want to print the Oracle version in my Windows command prompt output.

Windows command prompt execution:

```
C:\programfiles\PUTTY>putty.exe -ssh uname@ip -pw pwd -m windowsscriptpath/test.sh
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? I got struck here.. Is there any option to execute the unix server script directly from windows since shell script is working fine in unix server

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `sqlplus -V` sends its output to stderr (file descriptor 2) rather than stdout (file descriptor 1). In order to redirect stderr, use `2>>`:

```
sqlplus -V 2>> /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: Got an error when tried above command

Error 6 initialising SQL*Plus
SP2-0067: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your oracle software directory

/usr/oracle2/product/11.2.0/bin
Completed